# Direct product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, direct-sum, direct-product

I know of direct sum in the category of Hilbert spaces. Is there a concept of direct product too, wherein one can consider arbitrary tuples ? (looks like a no, as in order to talk about convergence etc, one would need countably many non zero vectors)

Comment: Do you mean $H \times H$?

Comment: No, over arbitrary (possibly uncountable) index set